# Weird failure of formals()

Tags: r

Why does this R code fail?

```
test1 <- function(x) {
  frame.idx <- sys.nframe()

  caller.call <- sys.calls()[[frame.idx - 1]]
  caller.name <- caller.call[[1]]
  caller.args <- names(formals(as.character(caller.name)))
  
  cat(as.character(caller.call), "  ", caller.args, '\n')
}

test2 <- function(y) {
  test1(y)
}

# A. Direct call:
test2(y=5)      # "test2 5    y"

# B. Call via a different name:
ff <- test2
ff(y=4)         # "ff 4    y"
  
# C. Call with ellipses:
test3 <- function(...) { test2(...) }
test3(y=2)      # "test2 ...    y"

# D. Call after match.fun to the ellipses version:
g <- match.fun("test3")
g(y=1)          # "test2 ...    y"

# Everything succeeds, until -
# E. Call with match.fun via ellipses, to a non-ellipsis version
test4 <- function(FUN, ...) {
  f <- match.fun(FUN)
  f(...)
}
test4("test2")   # Fails! "object 'f' of mode 'function' was not found"

# Note that this succeeds..
test4("test3")   # wtf
```

It fails for an invocation of `R --vanilla` too (i.e., zero packages). I currently suspect it's a core-R issue, but might be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yours is a problem related to environments.

A function can "see" what is created inside its own environment, what is created inside its parent's environment, what is created inside its parent's parent's environment, and so on.

`test1`, `test2`, `test3`, `test4` are created in the Global Environment.

```
environment(test1)
#> <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

`f` is created in the environment of `test4`. `test1` can't look inside a "brother" environment (only parent!): what is created inside `test4` cannot be seeing by `test1`.

When you enter in `test1` through `test4("test2")`, `test4`'s environment is the calling environment: that's what `parent.frame()` recalls.

`test4("test3")` works because `test2` was created in the GlobalEnv.

---

The error is caused by the function `formals`, because it cannot find the correspondent function (the internal `get` function fails), therefore it can't find its formals.

If you write your functions `test1` and `test2` in this way, your code will work as expected:

```
test1 <- function(x, env = parent.frame()) {
 frame.idx <- sys.nframe()
 
 caller.call <- sys.calls()[[frame.idx - 1]]
 caller.name <- caller.call[[1]]
 caller.args <- names(formals(as.character(caller.name), envir = env))
 
 cat(as.character(caller.call), "  ", caller.args, '\n')
}

test2 <- function(y) {
 test1(y, env = parent.frame())
}
```

---

To learn a bit more about environments I totally suggest you this:

https://adv-r.hadley.nz/environments.html

Comment: I'm working in R3.4 and formals() there doesn't have an envir argument - but I used this idea to solve my issue. Brilliant.

Comment: @OfekShilon  you should move to `R4.x` ASAP, as sooner or later stick with 3.x will lead to sadness and incompatibility with the world in general.